# Как сделать чтобы другой человек мог локально подключится к ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ec2

`aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-01bc990364452ab3e --instance-type t2.micro --user-data https://myfiles109.s3.amazonaws.com/user-data-script.sh --key-name it-step-testvm-secretkey --security-group-ids sg-0ad3a9d1ae0f84008`   --Я создаю по этой команде но тот скрипт который у меня загружен в хранилище не выполняется. Если тот же скрипт локально на компьютере то выполняется---